jQuery UI Selectable how to set default value
I want to select item with id="Today" by default.
Here is my HTML:
<ol id="selectable_date">
  <li id="Today" class="ui-widget-content">Today</li>,
  <li id="Tomorrow" class="ui-widget-content">Tomorrow</li>,
  <li id="AfterTomorrow" class="ui-widget-content">After Tomorrow</li>,
  <li id="InWeek" class="ui-widget-content">In Week</li>
</ol>

Here is my js code:
$("#selectable_date").selectable({
  selected: function (event, ui) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(ui);
    var id = $(".ui-selected").attr("id");
    ...
  }
});

How can I implement that?

I think if you use class="ui-widget-content ui-selected" it might be selected by default.

For my situation I resolved it in this way:
$("#selectable_date #Today").addClass("ui-selected");
$("#selectable_date").selectable("option", "value", "Today");
Maybe it will help somebody. It's hardcoded I think and it would be good to add event to jquery ui selectable to set values programmatically to avoid setting css class manually

It doesn't matter whether you set the class in code or in HTML.
